# proofs about regular expressions

Tags: regex, types, proof, coq, agda

Does anyone know any examples of the following?

1. Proof developments about [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts) (possibly extended with [backreferences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages)) in proof assistants (such as [Coq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq)).
2. Programs in dependently-typed languages (such as [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/agda.php)) about regular expressions.

Comment: According to "Mastering Regular Expressions" (a book I recommend, see http://regex.info/) regular expressions are quite non-regular in fact due to their enhanced abilities, so mathematical theory is only available for simple/basic regex types. Does this have implications to use them in proof assistance?

Comment: Yes, it does: it makes proofs more complicated :) In fact, by "regular expressions" I mean the basic ones that are strictly defined in formal language theory. I'd like to know if there were attempts to specify backreferences or other non-regular constructions. I'm aware of quite limited formalisations of basic r.e. in Nuprl and Coq. Since these formalisations stemmed from theory, rather than programming practice, they didn't account for non-regular features.

Answer (score 13):

[Certified Programming with Dependent Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/MoreDep.html) has a section on creating a verified regular expression matcher. [Coq Contribs](https://coq.inria.fr/contribs) has an [automata contribution](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/coq/pylons/coq/pylons/contribs/view/Automata/trunk) that might be useful. Jan-Oliver Kaiser formalized the equivalence between regular expressions, finite automata and the Myhill-Nerode characterization in Coq for his [bachelors thesis](http://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/~jokaiser/bachelor.php).

Comment: Right, I have also noted this paragraph in CPDT a few weeks ago. It does hit the ball. As per the automata contribution, it certainly is. However, it uses axioms. E.g., 4 axioms in the proof that regular languages are defined by NFAs (module RatReg). A proof without axioms is also possible (but not contained in the Coq contributions).

Answer (score 10):

Moreira, Pereira & de Sousa, [On the Mechanisation of Kleene Algebra in Coq](http://www.ncc.up.pt/kat/mech_ka_in_coq.pdf) gives a nice verified construction of the Antimirov derivative of regexps in Coq.  It's pretty easy to read off a CFA from this construction, and to compute the intersection of regexps.

I'm not sure why you separate Coq from dependently typed programming: Coq essentially is programming in a polymorphic dependently typed lambda calculus with inductive types (i.e., CIC, the calculus of inductive constructions).

I've never heard of a formalisation of regexps in a dependently typed language, nor have I heard of something such as an Antimirov-like derivative for regexps with backtracking, but Becchi & Crowley, [Extending Finite Automata to Efficiently Match Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions](http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~pcrowley/a25-becchi.pdf) provide a notion of finite-state automata that matches a Perl-like regexp languages.  That might attractive to formalisers in the near future.

Answer (score 7):

See [Perl Regular Expression Matching is NP-Hard](http://perl.plover.com/NPC/)

> Regex matching is NP-hard when regexes are allowed to have backreferences.
>
> [Reduction of 3-CNF-SAT to Perl Regular Expression Matching](http://perl.plover.com/NPC/NPC-3SAT.html)
>
> [...] 3-CNF-SAT is NP-complete. If there
> were an efficient (polynomial-time)
> algorithm for computing whether or not
> a regex matched a certain string, we
> could use it to quickly compute
> solutions to the 3-CNF-SAT problem,
> and, by extension, to the knapsack
> problem, the travelling salesman
> problem, etc. etc.

Comment: Even more than that: regular expression pattern matching with backreferences has been proved to be NP-complete by Alfred Aho quite some time ago by reduction from the vertex-cover problem. See Theorem 6.2 from [A. V. Aho. Algorithms for finding patterns in strings. In Jan van Leeuwen, editor, Handbook of Theoretical Computer Science, volume A: Algorithms and Complexity, pages 255–300. The MIT Press, 1990].

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any development that treats regular expressions by themselves.

Finite automata, however, relevant since [NFAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_state_machine) are the standard way to match those regular expressions, have been studied in [NuPRL](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Info/Projects/NuPRL/nuprl.html). Have a look at : [Robert L. Constable, Paul B. Jackson, Pavel Naumov, Juan Uribe.  *Constructively Formalizing Automata Theory*](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/pbj/papers/auto.ps.gz).

Should you be interested in approaching those formal languages through [algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup#History), esp. developing [finite semigroup theory](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=576708), there are a [number](http://coq.inria.fr/coq/distrib/current/contribs/Algebra.html) of [algebra libraries](http://www.mizar.org/library/) developed in various theorem provers that you could think of using, with [one particularly efficient in a finite setting](http://www.msr-inria.inria.fr/Projects/math-components/math-components-index).

Answer (score 5):

The proof assistant Isabelle/HOL ships a number of formalized proofs regarding regular expressions (without back reference):
http://afp.sourceforge.net/browser_info/devel/HOL/Regular-Sets/

([here](http://www4.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/~krauss/papers/rexp.pdf) is a paper by the authors regarding what they did exactly).

Another approach is to characterize regular expressions via [Myhill-Nerode Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem):
http://www.dcs.kcl.ac.uk/staff/urbanc/Publications/itp-11.pdf