# Defining a finite automata Coq

Tags: coq, finite-automata, language-theory

I am learning Coq and I'd like to use it to formalize Regular languages theory, specially finite automata. Let's say I have a structure for an automata as follows:

```
Record automata : Type := {
dfa_set_states : list state;
init_state : state;
end_state : state;
dfa_func: state -> terminal -> state;
}.
```

Where state is an inductive type as:

```
Inductive state:Type :=
S.
```

And the type terminal terminal is

```
Inductive terminal:Type :=
a | b.
```

I am trying to define it so later I'll be able to generalize the definition for any regular language. For now, I'd want to construct an automata which recognizes the language (a * b *), which is all words over the {a,b} alphabet. Does anyone have an idea on how to build some kind of fixpoint function that will run the word (which I see as a list of terminal) and tell me if that automata recgonizes that word or not? Any idea/help will be greatly apreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Erick.

Comment: This is quite hard to do in Coq as every function must be terminating. You can have a look to a couple of solutions at http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.MoreDep.html and http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/coq/V8.2pl1/contribs/Automata.html . A much simpler approach is if you add to your function a "fuel" parameter, that is to say, the number of characters you will allow your recognizer to work. Then, you should be able to prove it works when the fuel is greater or equal than the word's length.

Comment: Did you mean `(a | b)*` for the language of all words over the {a,b} alphabet?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/897595/2747511) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're restricting yourself to regular languages, this is quite simple: you just have to use a fold. Here is a sample:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Record dfa (S A : Type) := DFA {
  initial_state : S;
  is_final : S -> bool;
  next : S -> A -> S
}.

Definition run_dfa S A (m : dfa S A) (l : list A) : bool :=
  is_final m (fold_left (next m) l (initial_state m)).
```

This snippet is a little bit different from your original definition in that the state and alphabet components are now type parameters of the DFA, and in that I have replaced the end state with a predicate that answers whether we are in an accepting state or not.  The `run_dfa` function simply iterates the transition function of the DFA starting from the initial state, and then tests whether the last state is an accepting state.

You can use this infrastructure to describe pretty much any regular language.  For instance, here is an automaton for recognizing `a*b*`:

```
Inductive ab := A | B.

Inductive ab_state : Type :=
  ReadA | ReadB | Fail.

Definition ab_dfa : dfa ab_state ab := {|
  initial_state := ReadA;
  is_final s := match s with Fail => false | _ => true end;
  next s x :=
    match s, x with
    | ReadB, A => Fail
    | ReadA, B => ReadB
    | _, _ => s
    end
|}.
```

We can prove that this automaton does what we expect. Here is a theorem that says that it accepts strings of the sought language:

```
Lemma ab_dfa_complete n m : run_dfa ab_dfa (repeat A n ++ repeat B m) = true.
Proof.
  unfold run_dfa. rewrite fold_left_app.
  assert (fold_left (next ab_dfa) (repeat A n) (initial_state ab_dfa) = ReadA) as ->.
  { now simpl; induction n as [| n IH]; simpl; trivial. }
  destruct m as [|m]; simpl; trivial.
  induction m as [|m IH]; simpl; trivial.
Qed.
```

We can also state a converse, that says that it accepts only strings of that language, and nothing else. I have left the proof out; it shouldn't be hard to figure it out.

```
Lemma ab_dfa_sound l :
  run_dfa ab_dfa l = true ->
  exists n m, l = repeat A n ++ repeat B m.
```

Unfortunately, there is not much we can do with this representation besides running the automaton. In particular, we cannot minimize an automaton, test whether two automata are equivalent, etc.  These functions also need to take as arguments lists that enumerate all elements of the state and alphabet types, `S` and `A`.

Comment: Arthur, I now came across another question: you say with this representation, we are not available to test whether two automata are equivalent nor minimize them. Do you have any idea on how we could represent an automata so we could be able to do it? I am looking forward also to have a way to convert a regular grammar to an finite automata, and those functions will be useful.